# Creating meaningful suggestions based on an array of tags

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, search-suggestion

I have a project where there is a catalogue of items, each with an array of tags. I would like to present items that are similar, based on these tags.

Something like this (but with a much larger data set):

```
{
    "item": {
        "description":"thing",
        "tags": ["a","b","c","e","f"]
    },
    "item": {
        "description":"thing",
        "tags": ["a","b"]
    },
    "item": {
        "description":"thing",
        "tags": ["a","c"]
    },
    "item": {
        "description":"thing",
        "tags": ["b","c"]
    }
}
```

Two things I have tried so far:

First was a straight intersection between the tags on the individual item, and other items that have one or more of the same tags. This works well, but in cases where a tag is somewhat generic (think, tagged with something like "music" where they are all musical items), the number of returned items is huge.

The second one was a slightly crazy idea, where I turned the array of tags into a string, and calculated the levenshtein difference. This works for items that have a length that is approximately the same or larger, but is clunky. Still, it did trim off a lot of the fat that first approach returned. It is not the right way, but wanted to show what I am aiming for. Implemented it like this:

```
// snip: this is inside a BB collection

    getSimilarByTag: function(tags, ignore){
            var hits = [];

            if (tags) {

                this.filter(function(item){

                    if (item.get('cat') === ignore){
                        return; // no need to include
                    };

                    var itemTags = item.get('tags');
                    var result = _.intersection(tags, itemTags);

                    if (result.length) {
                        // calc levenshtein distance between the intersection and the search array
                        var dist = _.str.levenshtein(result.join(' '), tags.join(' '));
                        if (Math.log(dist) < 1.5) { // this value needs tuning?
                            hits.push(item.toJSON());   
                        } else {
                            // based on our magic number above, ignore this
                        }
                    };
                });
            }

            return hits;
        }
```

I'm doing all my code in javascript, using backbone and underscore. However, the language is not so important - just curious about what kind of technique or algorithm might give a better set of results.

Comment: Is there any possibility of using categories as well as tags? So 'music' would be a category, and tags could be 'classical','punk'...that way you could simply dismiss anything that's not in the same category, and then select items according to an intersection of (a variable minimum number of) tags.

Comment: Unfortunately not - and actually categories could just be seen as some kind of "master tag", which doesn't really get me much further. Thanks for input though!

Comment: If a returned dataset may be to big we usually (as you must be well aware of) return the set in chunks, i.e. the sql limit. Why not consider implementing such a technique? It seems as if you are asking for the impossible, loads of data is loads of data no matter what the language it is.

Comment: I'm trying to work out what the most applicable data would be though, not just how to handle it, going beyond intersections.

Comment: What is your question really?  Are you just asking what's the best way to create a similarity score between two arrays of strings?

Answer (score 1):

A simple routine for most applicable data could be, return matches in order of size of tag intersection, with a limited return count. If you could weight certain tags as being more important then you could use that to adjust the returned order. For example if the user has previously bought items from the catalogue, then the tags linked to their purchases could have an increased score in the order algorithm.